# Spring Boot Security - Sub Urls are unauthorized

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am doing my first Spring Security project and I am struggling to solve this bug. I want every URL starting with /user to be authorized and then get the response associated with the URL.

This is configuration code:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

When I access /user using postman I get the expected response. But when i try to access /user/foo on postman I get error code 401: unauthorised even with the valid username and password.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-11T12:38:17.805+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/user/foo"
}
```

Same thing happens with /admin/... URLs, /admin is accessible but /admin/foo is unauthorized.

URLS are /user/{username} and /admin/{username}. Considering  foo as the username. I am not sure if I have used wildcard in the right way or not.

Also /user/{username} is applied for GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I tried `http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()....` but it didn't work.

Comment: No. I already have the user object in the database